# Create N digit random words from an array

Tags: javascript

I want to create a 4 digit random word from this array.

```
const words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'];
```

for that I coded like this..

```
const word = (
    words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)] +
    words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)] +
    words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)] +
    words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)]
    );
console.log(word) // afab
```

For this I need to repeat the code `words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)]` again if I need 6 digit or 10 digit.

How can I write the code using a variable that is easy to generate N digit random words without repeat the code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `Array.from` and get the word of `length` length

```
Array.from({ length }, () => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]).join("")
```

Create a dynamic length using

```
arr.length  // instead of 9(Don't hardcode)
```

```js
const words = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "k"];

function generateRandomWord(arr, length) {
  return Array
          .from({ length },() => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)])
          .join("");
}

console.log(generateRandomWord(words, 4));
console.log(generateRandomWord(words, 8));
console.log(generateRandomWord(words, 12));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function recursiveRandomWord(words, len) {
  if (len == 0) {
    return '';
  }
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)] + recursiveRandomWord(words, len - 1);
}

const words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let length = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 4;
  console.log(`Length ${length}, Word: ${recursiveRandomWord(words, length)}`);
}
```

```js
const words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'];

function randomWord(arr, len) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result.push(
      words[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)
      ]
    );
  }
  return result.join('');
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let length = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 4;
  console.log(`Length ${length}, Word: ${randomWord(words, length)}`);
}
```

Note: Will work in older browser for eg: Internet Explorer 6

Answer (score 2):

This is a functional approach. First call you pass the target array to choose items from, then the next call is the amount.

```js
const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];

const words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'];

function randomNum(target) {
  const newRandomNum = (num = 1, val = "") => {
    val += (target[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)])
    if (num === 1) return val;
    return newRandomNum(--num, val);
  }
  return newRandomNum;
}

console.log(randomNum(numbers)(5));
console.log(randomNum(numbers)(10));

console.log(randomNum(words)(5));
console.log(randomNum(words)(10));
```

An improvement you could make is to check the type of the target array, then use += for strings, and another method for numbers since you don't want to add them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'];
const N = 4;

let word = Array(N).fill(0).map(item=>words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)]).join('');
console.log(word);
```

Comment: Why join the array before accessing it? It seems redundant since accessing an array and accessing a string are both O(1) and indexes stay the same

Comment: You are totally right. I updated my answer. Tnx.